# C++ Builder [C++ Error] sysmac.h(58): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, vcl

I want to create a C++ Builder DLL project that doesn't use VCL. But I get this error in sysmac. Does anyone know the possible cause of this error?

Comment: post the code that causes the problem

Comment: It is a large project and the unit that contains the error line, is C++Builder's system unit.

Comment: @samir105--look at this essay: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html  Even with a specific error message none of us are going to be able to give you intelligent advice without seeing your source code.

Comment: Are you including the VCL anywhere in your dll project?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess (because it's about 5 years since I would with C++ Builder) it's because sysmac.h requires the VCL, from this [VCL Overview](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31668&seqNum=2)

> The __declspec keyword is provided for
>   language support with the VCL to
>   overcome the previously mentioned
>   items. The sysmac.h file provides
>   macros that you should use if you need
>   to use this keyword. The __declspec
>   variations are discussed next

Comment: I don't need sysmac and VCL. Can I export functions in DLL without "__declspec" in C++Builder?

Comment: I know you can build native Win32 libs & dlls with C++ builder (I used to do it) but don't have a copy handly anymore, and it's years since I used it. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly (C++)

A declaration has an extra or incorrect termination symbol, such as a semicolon placed after a function body.

A C++ member function declared in a class with a semicolon between the header and the opening left brace also generates this error.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/E2040_Declaration_terminated_incorrectly_%28C%2B%2B%29

Answer (score 0):

This means that you're including a VCL header somewhere in your project - most likely in a file that is compiled as C unit (hence the syntax errors).

You can turn on "Extended error information" in the project options to track down the responsible module.